# StateMachineBase.java not updated when designer.jar saves theme file

Tags: codenameone

StateMachineBase.java is not updating.  I've tried moving the file so that the designer should re-create it, I've tried running it from the command line (no error messages are displayed).

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot designer.jar and the StateMachineBase.java file?

the designer.jar file has a last modified date of Sept 1, 2015.   I normally work in IntelliJ Idea but given that I'm running the designer from the command line, I assume this helps eliminate the IDE from the equation.

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this?  what files or settings could affect the behavior of the Designer as it writes the StateMachineBase.java file?

Here is the contents of my codenameone_settings.properties file:

```
#
#Fri Mar 04 17:16:27 EST 2016
codename1.ios.appid=OBFUSCATED.ca.zettabot.trainingtool
codename1.ios.release.provision=
codename1.arg.rim.obfuscation=true
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=nbproject/nativej2me.res
codename1.arg.ios.project_type=ios
codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation=UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait\:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft\:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
codename1.displayName=TrainingTool
guiResource=theme.res
codename1.android.keystoreAlias=
codename1.ios.release.certificate=
codename1.android.keystorePassword=
codename1.arg.ios.dsym=false
codename1.arg.android.release=true
package=generated
codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden=false
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.android.keystore=
mainForm=SplashScreen
userClassAbs=C\:\\Users\\vankej\\Desktop\\Personal\\android\\codename1\\TrainingTool\\src\\userclasses\\StateMachine.java
codename1.vendor=Codename One
codename1.arg.win.ver=8
codename1.arg.zooz.sandbox=false
codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword=
codename1.mainName=MyApplication
codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword=
codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon=false
codename1.arg.vserv.scaleMode=false
codename1.ios.debug.certificate=
libVersion=99
codename1.arg.vserv.category=29
codename1.arg.ios.application_exits=false
codename1.secondaryTitle=TrainingTool
codename1.description=
codename1.ios.debug.provision=
baseClass=src/generated/StateMachineBase.java
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=0
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.version=1.0
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.arg.android.debug=false
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
codename1.arg.vserv.transition=300000
userClass=src/userclasses/StateMachine.java
codename1.arg.ios.includePush=false
codename1.packageName=ca.zettabot.trainingtool
```

Here is the command line output of the designer command when I open and try to save the theme file:

```
C:\Users\vankej\Desktop\Personal\android\codename1\TrainingTool>java -jar designer.jar src\theme.res > output.txt
2016-03-08 21:59:34.602:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.0.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2016-03-08 21:59:34.638:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000 STARTING
Mar 08, 2016 9:59:34 PM org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage getId
WARNING: unspecified resource Application.id using ResourceEditorApp
Mar 08, 2016 9:59:34 PM org.jdesktop.application.LocalStorage getId
WARNING: unspecified resource Application.vendorId using UnknownApplicationVendor
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/vankej/Desktop/Personal/android/codename1/TrainingTool/res/theme.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.]
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.openFileWithXMLSupport(EditableResources.java:409)
        at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView$LoadResourceFileAction.exectute(ResourceEditorView.java:4112)
        at com.codename1.ui.resource.util.BlockingAction.run(BlockingAction.java:88)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/vankej/Desktop/Personal/android/codename1/TrainingTool/res/theme.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.codename1.designer.UserInterfaceEditor.persistToXML(UserInterfaceEditor.java:3161)
        at com.codename1.designer.UserInterfaceEditor.persistToXML(UserInterfaceEditor.java:3083)
        at com.codename1.designer.UserInterfaceEditor.appendComponentXMLBody(UserInterfaceEditor.java:2821)
        at com.codename1.designer.UserInterfaceEditor.persistToXML(UserInterfaceEditor.java:3510)
        at com.codename1.designer.UserInterfaceEditor.persistToXML(UserInterfaceEditor.java:3083)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.writeUIXml(EditableResources.java:1287)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.saveXMLFile(EditableResources.java:1236)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EditableResources.saveXML(EditableResources.java:1311)
        at com.codename1.designer.ResourceEditorView$SaveResourceFileAction.exectute(ResourceEditorView.java:4295)
        at com.codename1.ui.resource.util.BlockingAction.run(BlockingAction.java:88)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you are running the designer from the command line what is its output when you try to save your changes (that's the point where this gets updated). Does it print anything? What is the content of your codenameone_settings.properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of the designer when running it from the command line.

Make sure your `codenameone_settings.properties` is a valid file and contains the following.

This must point at a valid res file which must be the one containing your GUI's:

```
guiResource=theme.res
```

This must point at the generated package for the `StatemachineBase.java`:

```
package=generated
```

This must point at the `StateMachine.java` source file, not as crucial but important:

```
userClass=src/userclasses/StateMachine.java
```

This must point at a valid main form within your GUI:

```
mainForm=Main
```

You can try and regenerate the state machine directly from the command line using the command:

```
java -jar path_to_designer_1.jar -regen path_to_resfile.res
```

I'd really like to know if that works or fails.

Comment: Shai, thanks for the hints.  I've checked and all of the settings are exactly what they should be (I don't recall editing the properties manually at all and especially not around the time the problem came up).  there were no command line error messages. I will update the quesiton with my settings file for review. One thing that jumped out at me was that when I was looking for "userClass" i found a line "userClassAbs=C\:\\Users\\vankej..." (I truncated it here for brevity).

Comment: I added a way to generate the source from command line to my answer. I'm not sure what could possibly go wrong here. Are you running from command line with the javaw command? If so it won't print anything to the console, make sure you are using the java command which does.

Comment: you were right I wasn't using java -jar.   the -regen command DID successfully generate the StateMachineBase.java (YAY!!!) but the designer still won't update the file.  I captured the command line output from opening and trying to save the theme.  I've added it to the original post for review.  thanks for your help here... I was losing my mind thinking I'd wasted all my work.

Comment: Try unchecking `File->XML Team Mode` there seems to be a corruption in the XML.

Comment: Thanks Shai,  As soon as I turned off XML Team Mode and saved, the StateMachineBase updated.  Good to note for future reference!